# PHP upload image replace old

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, replace

Ok so I am working on a backoffice at work.
This is my first experience on PHP so my code will most likely not be that great.

Here is what I am working on:

The client must be able to upload a image + title + description of a product, it must that show that product on the main page.
After that he must be able to delete or modify that item.

So the upload is working, I managed to show the product, delete it, and modify it.

The only problem is: When I modify with a new image it doesn't replace the old one in the directory (images take on the id of the sql input, example 0.jpg -> 1.jpg -2.jpg etc.)

So I will show here my upload script and modify :

Upload:

```
<?php
     include("config.php");

$dir = "../images/";
$dir = $dir . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$image = ($_FILES['image']['name']);
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$uploadedfiletype = $_FILES['image']['type']; 

if (!($uploadedfiletype =="image/pjpeg" OR $uploadedfiletype =="image/jpeg" OR $uploadedfiletype =="image/jpg")){
      echo "Image must be jpg file";
}else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $dir)){
    $sql="INSERT INTO test (title, description, position) VALUES ('$title','$description','$position')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  $newname = "../images/" . mysql_insert_id() . ".jpg";
  rename ("../images/$image","$newname");    
  $orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("../image/$newname");
  $sm_image = imagecreatetruecolor(96,96);
  imagecopyresampled($sm_image,$orig_image,0,0,0,0,96,96,imagesx($orig_image),imagesy($orig_image));
  imagejpeg($sm_image, $newname, 100);
  echo 'Upload good <a href="connected.php">Retour</a>';
}else{
    echo "Problem";
}
?>
```

And here is my modify script (basicly the same thing but with UPDATE for sql):

```
<?php

    include("config.php");

$dir = "../images/";
$dir = $dir . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];
$image = ($_FILES['image']['name']);
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$uploadedfiletype = $_FILES['image']['type']; 

unlink('../images/$id');

if (!($uploadedfiletype =="image/pjpeg" OR $uploadedfiletype =="image/jpeg" OR $uploadedfiletype =="image/jpg")){
      echo "L'image doit être en .jpg ou .jpeg";
}else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $dir)){ 
  $sql="UPDATE test SET title='$title', description='$description' WHERE id='$id'";
    if (!mysql_query($sql)){
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  $newname = "../images/" . mysql_insert_id() . ".jpg";
  rename ("../images/$image","$newname");    
  $orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("../image/$newname");
  $sm_image = imagecreatetruecolor(96,96);
  imagecopyresampled($sm_image,$orig_image,0,0,0,0,96,96,imagesx($orig_image),imagesy($orig_image));
  imagejpeg($sm_image, $newname, 100);
  echo 'Modif réussi <a href="connected.php">Retour</a>';
}else{
    echo "Un probleme est survenue";
}

 ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you got a typo error near `unlink('../images/$id');` I mean, PHP doesn't compile $id within the single quotes.

Try doing `unlink("../images/$id");` or `unlink('../images/'.$id);`

If it still doesn't work, You might have a right issue. Try debugging it by doing `var_dump(unlink("../images/$id"))` if it returns false, it means deletion failed.

If so, try creating a new file, using a sha1 hash for example:

`$dir = "../images/".sha1(rand())."-".basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);`

This will create a new unique name for each uploaded file. It will store the old images, but under different name.
Just call them differently into your database

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. So I tried with your unlinks, nothing happens, I also used var_dump and the return is: bool(false), any tips from their ? I would really like to try to solve this instead of creating a new image. Thanks again !

Comment: Are you sure the file Exists ? Try `var_dump(file_exists("../images/$id"));`. If still nothing does, try full path using `unlink(realpath("../images/$id"));`

Comment: Still getting the exact same thing. Since I had a doubt I echoed $id, it did return the id (in this case 52), so stupid thing is i just wasnt ading the .jpg, s I used: unlink('../images/'.$id.'.jpg'); and it does delete the file, but doesnt upload the new one

Comment: Try replacing `$newname = "../images/" . mysql_insert_id() . ".jpg";` by `$newname = "../images/" . $id . ".jpg";`

Answer (score 1):

change in `unlink('../images/$id');`
assign `'../images/$id'` to a variable and then use : `unlink($variable_name);`
it will be good for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'TableName';
```

Comment: Please explain your answers